# How to block all wakelock and wakeup events of Google Play Services running Android 4+?

Tags: battery-life, google-play-services, wakelock

Android 4+. With some apps as betterbatterystats, I identified that many wakelock of Google Play Service is eating my battery when my device is in deep sleep. I already study this phenomena further, with many tests and apps. There is no doubt on the root cause. Now, and I wish to block all wakeup / wakelock events of Google Play Service. How to do this on rooted device ?

Comment: Have you tried Greenify to cut wake-up paths?

Comment: Your edit now makes my answer irrelevant. No problem with that but please do remember to give all details in future so that efforts are not wasted by you and potential answerers. Deleting my answer. All the best

Comment: Remove Google services? Flash a custom ROM that does not contain Gapps, and do not install any Google services or Gapps package.